# Android Spanned imageView

Tags: android, imageview, spanned

I've created a Spanned object that displays an image along with some text.
Is it possible to get that imageView object so I could set it's background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ImageView` object, so you cannot get it.

If you have an `ImageSpan` -- either that you added yourself directly or via something like an `<img>` tag in HTML you parsed with `Html.fromHtml()` -- you can get at the `Drawable` for the image. However, that is directly rendered to the canvas, not by way of an `ImageView` widget.

You can wrap the `ImageSpan` in a `BackgroundColorSpan`. Or, make sure that your image has the proper background already (e.g., use a `LayerListDrawable`).